# Convert MongoDB time to epoch time - Python

Tags: python, mongodb, datetime, time, pymongo

I have a mongodb time as `objectid("5217a543dd99a6d9e0f74702")`.

How to convert it to epoch time in Python. (UTC timezone and also EST timezone)

Answer (score 2):

`ObjectId.generation_time` gives you the time the ObjectId was generated, in UTC:

```
>>> from bson import ObjectId
>>> ObjectId("5217a543dd99a6d9e0f74702").generation_time
datetime.datetime(2013, 8, 23, 18, 9, 7, tzinfo=<bson.tz_util.FixedOffset object at 0x102920c90>)
```

[The documentation is here.](http://api.mongodb.org/python/current/api/bson/objectid.html#bson.objectid.ObjectId.generation_time)

To convert to Eastern Time, install pytz and:

```
>>> import pytz
>>> ny = pytz.timezone('America/New_York')
>>> gt = ObjectId("5217a543dd99a6d9e0f74702").generation_time
>>> ny.normalize(gt.astimezone(ny))
datetime.datetime(2013, 8, 23, 14, 9, 7, tzinfo=<DstTzInfo 'America/New_York' EDT-1 day, 20:00:00 DST>)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`ObjectId.getTimestamp()`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/ObjectId.getTimestamp/#ObjectId.getTimestamp) method to get the timestamp portion of the objectid as Date.

Once you have the Date object you can call any of the Date methods to get what you want.  In the shell, you could just hit TAB to get the list of all methods that are permitted:

```
> var myid = new ObjectId()
> myid
ObjectId("5331ba8163083f9b26efb5b3")
> var mytime = myid.getTimestamp()
> mytime
ISODate("2014-03-25T17:18:57Z")
> mytime.<TAB>
mytime.constructor            mytime.getUTCFullYear(
mytime.getDate(               mytime.getUTCHours(
mytime.getDay(                mytime.getUTCMilliseconds(
mytime.getFullYear(           mytime.getUTCMinutes(
mytime.getHours(              mytime.getUTCMonth(
mytime.getMilliseconds(       mytime.getUTCSeconds(
mytime.getMinutes(            mytime.getYear(
mytime.getMonth(              mytime.hasOwnProperty(
mytime.getSeconds(            mytime.propertyIsEnumerable(
mytime.getTime(               mytime.setDate(
mytime.getTimezoneOffset(     mytime.setFullYear(
mytime.getUTCDate(            mytime.setHours(
mytime.getUTCDay(             mytime.setMilliseconds(
```

Note: I'm not familiar with Python, but the same concepts would apply

Comment: there is no ObjectId.getTimestamp() in Python 2.7

Comment: I haven't used Python and MongoDb but with the C# driver, I was able to deserialize the JSON value into a DateTime object.